# Firebase for Unity3d, always test mode authentication Unity Editor

Tags: unity-game-engine, firebase, firebase-authentication

Today I've tried the Firebase for Unity3d for its Authentication system.

When I try to log in on Unity editor it will be always like test mode authentication, That the register/login data will not storing on auth database and can not receive the Token which I want to use it on my cloud function to validate the user.

I have to build and try it, I have tried it on my Android device and it works fine but it's a waste of time to build it.

How can I solve it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following the [Issue](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-unity/issues/3) It's not possible to use authentication on Unity editor (And Standalone also) so I will create my own web-service for that.

Comment: Are you creating a web services for the testing? can you share it? ;)